# Why is Registry value not changing in C# as I want it to be?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

```
        public UserControl2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XblGameSave", true);
        uint value = Convert.ToUInt32(key.GetValue("Start"));
        RegistryKey key1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XboxNetApiSvc", true);
        uint value1 = Convert.ToUInt32(key1.GetValue("Start"));
        RegistryKey key2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XboxGipSvc", true);
        uint value2 = Convert.ToUInt32(key2.GetValue("Start"));
        RegistryKey key3 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XblAuthManager", true);
        uint value3 = Convert.ToUInt32(key3.GetValue("Start"));
        if (value+value1+value2+value3 == 16)
        {
            Disable_Xbox_Services.IsChecked = true;
        }
        if (Disable_Xbox_Services.IsChecked == true)
        {
            key.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            key1.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            key2.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            key3.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

        }

        else if (Disable_Xbox_Services.IsChecked == false)
        {
            key.SetValue("Start", 3, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            key1.SetValue("Start", 3, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            key2.SetValue("Start", 3, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            key3.SetValue("Start", 3, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }

    }
```

This is my C# User control code

```
 <CheckBox Name="Disable_Xbox_Services" FontSize="26" Foreground="GhostWhite" >Disable Xbox services</CheckBox>
```

This is my CheckBox XAML code.
So what is happening with me here is that when I am running my app and Checking my checkbox, it doesn't change the registry value but when it is unchecked, it changes the value perfectly changed. There are no runtime errors as I have tried debugging it. I want the value to be changed whenever the checkbox is checked as I have mentioned in the code. Pls help me out.

Comment: Your whole code is in the constructor for UserControl2. The constructor only runs **once** when the UserControl2 is being uh... constructed. Then never again, unless you construct yet another UserControl2 instance (but creating another UserControl2 instance just to run some code you placed in its constructor doesn't really make sense, though) Either bind a viewmodel property to the checkbox. Or, if you are unfamiliar with MVVM and viewmodels, the checkbox also offers events that will be risen when the checkbox state changes which allows using old-fashioned event handlers.

Comment: If you're using WPF then you ought be be using MVVM and any change to the Registry should be happening in the view model. If you're not using MVVM then you need to handle the appropriate events of the `CheckBox` control. That would be `Checked` and `Unchecked`.

Comment: Also note that you quite likely need to run your program with elevated privileges (i.e., admin privileges). You are trying to modify stuff in the HKLM branch of the registry, which normally requires admin privileges unless you changed the ACL (permissions) of the registry branch(es)/folder(s) you are trying to modify.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason. Here is the right code:
Edit: I have used the Dispose method to dispose the registry keys.

```
public UserControl2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        
            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XblGameSave", true);
            RegistryKey key1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XboxNetApiSvc", true);
            RegistryKey key2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XboxGipSvc", true);
            RegistryKey key3 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XblAuthManager", true);
        try
        {
            uint value = Convert.ToUInt32(key.GetValue("Start"));
            uint value1 = Convert.ToUInt32(key1.GetValue("Start"));
            uint value2 = Convert.ToUInt32(key2.GetValue("Start"));
            uint value3 = Convert.ToUInt32(key3.GetValue("Start"));
            
                if (value + value1 + value2 + value3 == 16)
                {
                    Disable_Xbox_Services.IsChecked = true;
                }

        }
        finally
        {
            key?.Dispose();
            key1?.Dispose();
            key2?.Dispose();
            key3?.Dispose();
        }
        
        
    }
   

    private void Disable_Xbox_Services_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XblGameSave", true);
        RegistryKey key1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XboxNetApiSvc", true);
        RegistryKey key2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XboxGipSvc", true);
        RegistryKey key3 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XblAuthManager", true);
        try
        {
            key.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        finally
        {
            key?.Dispose();
        }
        try
        {
            key1.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        finally
        {
            key1?.Dispose();
        }
        try
        {
            key2.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        finally
        {
            key2?.Dispose();
        }
        try
        {
            key3.SetValue("Start", 4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        finally
        {
            key3?.Dispose();
        }

    }

    private void Disable_Xbox_Services_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XblGameSave", true);
        RegistryKey key1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XboxNetApiSvc", true);
        RegistryKey key2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XboxGipSvc", true);
        RegistryKey key3 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XblAuthManager", true);
        try
        {
            key.SetValue("Start", 3, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        finally
        {
            key?.Dispose();
        }
        try
        {
            key1.SetValue("Start", 3, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        finally
        {
            key1?.Dispose();
        }
        try
        {
            key2.SetValue("Start", 3, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        finally
        {
            key2?.Dispose();
        }
        try
        {
            key3.SetValue("Start", 3, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        finally
        {
            key3?.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Comment: `RegistryKey` instances are `IDisposable`'s. Nor do you need to keep them around in fields of an UserControl2 instance. It would be _much_ better to create the `RegistryKey` instances within your Checked/Unchecked methods and use the [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement together with them to ensure that they are being disposed properly after the method is finished using them. And you would/could then declare the string paths of these keys as `const string` fields instead.

Comment: I didn't understood what you are trying to say. Could you pls answer with the right code that I can use instead of this one?

Comment: @KrakenZ Better have a look at the [using keyword/IDisposable documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects) instead

Comment: What @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace is saying is: don't store the `key` in a field. Instead, create it when you need it, with a `using` block which will automatically dispose it.

Comment: Done. I have use the dispose method. Pls check if it's correct. BTW does dispose method improve the performance of the app or if not, then what is it's main use?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).